# SQL: Need assistance with this query

Tags: sql, if-statement, switch-statement, case

I hope the table names don't matter, because they're based on my database.  I will try to keep it as simple as possible.

This is what I need: Provide a list of Orthopaedic specialists with their assistants' name, and contact information.  If the doctor does not have an assistant, put "Unknown" on the report for Last Name.
Personal information is in a table called `Person`.  This includes contact information (`PhoneNumber`). Each doctor has an ID number called `PersonID`
Assistant name (`FirstName`,`LastName`) is in a table called `PersonContact`.

Here's What I have so far:

```
SELECT Person.FirstName
    ,Person.LastName
    ,Person.PhoneNumber
    ,PersonContact.FirstName
    ,PersonContact.Lastname
FROM Person
INNER JOIN PersonContact ON person.personID = PersonContactID
```

How can I make it that doctors who don't have assistants show up with "`Unknown`" for their assistant's names?

EDIT:  I've tried every suggestion here, but I'm getting straight "NULL" or "UNKNOWN" for every row.  I need it to say "UNKNOWN" when there is no entry for Personcontact.Firstname and/or Personcontact.Lastname.

Comment: Try using a `LEFT JOIN` and select `ISNULL(PersonContact.FirstName, 'Unknown'), ISNULL(PersonContact.LastName, 'Unknown')`. `ISNULL` may vary depending on your dbms.

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. **Not** `INNER JOIN`. An `INNER JOIN` will only select record where the Person exists in the PersonContact table.  `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will select all records in the Person table, and then any records in the PersonContact table.  If a Person doesn't exist in the PersonContact table, the Person will still get selected.  This has been suggested to you numerous times through comments and answers.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` to get all Persons, and any Contacts that are available, and use `COALESCE` to replace any NULL values with 'UNKNOWN'.

```
Select Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, Person.PhoneNumber, 
    COALESCE(PersonContact.FirstName, 'UNKNOWN') AS FirstName,
    COALESCE(PersonContact.Lastname, 'UNKNOWN') AS LastName
From Person
LEFT OUTER Join PersonContact
    On person.personID = PersonContactID
```

Comment: I haven't come into contact with COALESCE.
I'll be checking that out, Thanks!

Comment: It's like `ISNULL`, but you can check multiple fields for the first non-null character, and most RDBMS's support it

Comment: Upvoting this one, since this question isn't tagged `sql-server` or `tsql`

Answer (score 0):

Using a LEFT JOIN

```
FROM PERSON
LEFT JOIN PersonContact ON person.personID = PersonContactID
```

This will provide nulls where no contact is available.

Depending on your variety of SQL you can format those NULLS using some form of NULL replacement.
eg, in MSSQL

```
ISNULL(PersonContact.FirstName, '(unknown)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNULL() and a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT Person.FirstName     
,isnull(Person.LastName, 'Unknown') as LastName
,Person.PhoneNumber     
,PersonContact.FirstName     
,PersonContact.Lastname 
FROM Person LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonContact ON person.personID = PersonContactID
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a left join here; so something like this:

```
Select Person.FirstName,
       Person.LastName,
       Person.PhoneNumber,
       ISNULL(PersonContact.FirstName, 'Unknown') AS FirstName,
       ISNULL(PersonContact.Lastname, 'Unknown') AS LastName
From Person LEFT OUTER Join PersonContact
      On person.personID = PersonContactID
```